# routerlink not working in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have checked all the tutorial and didn't find, what i am doing wrong.

AppModule :

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
 import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 import {BlogComponent} from './blog/blog.component';
 import { PortfolioComponent } from './portfolio/portfolio.component';
 import { NavbarComponent } from './shared/navbar/navbar.component';
 import {TimelineComponent} from './timeline/timeline.component';
 import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';

 import { routing} from './app.routing';

 @NgModule({
   declarations: [
     AppComponent,
     PortfolioComponent,
     NavbarComponent,
     BlogComponent,
     TimelineComponent,
     HomeComponent
   ],
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     FormsModule,
     HttpModule,
     routing
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [
     AppComponent
   ]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
 </i>

 Navigation Bar 
 <i>
 <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li><a routerlink="/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a routerlink="/timeline">Timeline</a></li>
         <li><a routerlink="/blog">Blog</a></li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li><a href="#contact">Professionals</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact">Students</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
 </i>

 NGModule :
 <i>
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
 i

 import { routing} from './app.routing';

 @NgModule({

   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     FormsModule,
     HttpModule,
     routing
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [
     AppComponent
   ]
 })
```

Please check above code, anf please help me to find why routerlink is not wokring.

Comment: What's the error ? Where are your routes ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure the code you pasted is ordered correctly but I can see 2 mistakes.

First, you're setting the `routerlink` attribute instead of `routerLink`, notice it's case sensitive.

Second, I'm pretty sure you don't import RouterModule in the module with the relevant component, make sure you do that so you get access to the `routerLink` directive in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The code you are showing is correct.

I think that your problem is that you are not importing RouterModule (which is where component is declared) into the module which uses this template.

in the module that declares the component with this template add:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

then add it to your modules imports e.g.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: [MyComponent]
})
export class MyTemplatesModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

the anchor tag with the routerLink must be in the same place as de tag router-outlet